# how to integrate paypal in website

Tags: paypal

I have to make a paypal integration in my website for paying person.I found a simple code

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">

To pay with PayPal now please click on the PayPal icon below:

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@paypal.email"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order #{$order_id}"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$order_amount}"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="{$currency_iso_3}"><br>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://images.paypal.com/images/x-click-but01.gif" alt="Pay with PayPal"><br>
< /form>
```

Is this secure for payment ?

Comment: I answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404356/279147 I know it's 2 years later, but perhaps other people arriving here will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the information over [SSL/TSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

If all the certificates are current and valid, you should be fine (so [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks are less likely).

It is what banks and other financial and retail organizations are using - should be OK.

However, you did not really specify your requirements for secure integration - can you provide more information?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I am not making code for any BANK.One of my client want to pay their employee by paypal.So i have made a section for payment for each employee.So my client will click on pay button to pay employee.So click and payment for each employee.This is my module.Is the above code will be perfect foe this ?

Comment: @Ajay_kumar - should be fine.